# Bind scope variable to divs innerhtml

Tags: angularjs

I have a project where I have to use angular with a jquery rich text editor.

What I have is a text area inside a directive called `notes`

`<textarea class='newNote' id="newNoteText" ng-model="newnote"/>` to which I attach the jquery editor inside `notes` link function like so

`$(element).find('#newNoteText').redactor();`

The problem with that is that jquery editor only uses the textarea as a dummy so when I submit  the form `newnote` scope variable is empty.

What jquery editor does is it creates a div with a class `redactor_newNote` which contains whatever was in the textarea and the html needs to format it (bold tags, ordered/unordered lists, etc.)

So I thought I'd be clever and I attempted by attach `ng-model` dynamically like so (still inside `notes` link function)

`$compile($(element).find('.redactor_newNote').attr('ng-model', 'newnote'))(scope);`

This doesn't work because `ng-model` doesn't work with a div (it could also be because I am not using $compile correctly)

So basically what I need help with is figuring out how to take inner html of `'.redactor_newNote'` div and bind to a scope variable.

Thank you!

Comment: Any chance you could create an example online (like a jsfiddle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngModel` works for input elements, etc. because angular has a built-in `input` directive that connects the input's value to the model. You can write your own directive that does the same thing for the `redactor_newNote` div.

[The ngModelController documentation page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) has a great example on how to do this. It uses a `contenteditable` directive with `ngModel` to get the html content.

Comment: @Mattias Dailey Can you post some example code illustrating what you mean?